# How to select specific elements and find their index in a data.frame?

Tags: r, subset, dplyr, lapply

I would like to select specific elements of a `data.list` after processing it.

To get process parameters I describe the my problem in the reproducible example.
In the example code below, I have three sets of `data.list` each have 5 column.

Each `data.list` repeat theirselves three times each and each `data.list` assignet to unique number called `set_nbr` which defines these datasets.

```
#to create reproducible data (this part creates three sets of data each one repeats 3 times of those of Mx, My and Mz values along with set_nbr)
set.seed(1) 
data.list <- lapply(1:3, function(x) {
nrep <- 3
time <- rep(seq(90,54000,length.out=600),times=nrep) 
Mx <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(600,-0.014,0.012),decreasing=TRUE)))
My <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(600,-0.02,0.02),decreasing=TRUE)))
Mz <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(600,-1,1),decreasing=TRUE)))
df <- data.frame(time,Mx,My,Mz,set_nbr=x)
})
```

after applying some function I have output like this.

```
 result

       time     Mz           set_nbr
 1  27810 -1.917835e-03       1
 2  28980 -1.344288e-03       1
 3  28350 -3.426615e-05       1
 4  27900 -9.934413e-04       1
 5  25560 -1.016492e-02       2
 6  27360 -4.790767e-03       2
 7  28080 -7.062256e-04       2
 8  26550 -1.171716e-04       2
 9  26820 -2.495893e-03       3
 10 26550 -7.397865e-03       3
 11 26550 -2.574022e-03       3
 12 27990 -1.575412e-02       3
```

**My questions starts from here**.

1) How to get `min`,`middle` and `max` values of `time` column, for each `set_nbr`  ?

2) How to use evaluated `set_nbr` and `Mz` values inside of `data.list`?

In short;

After deciding the `min`,`middle` and `max` values from `time` column and corresponding `Mz` values for each `set_nbr` in `result`, I want to return back to original data.list and extract those columns of `Mx`, `My`, `Mz` according those of `set_nbr` and `Mz` values. Since each `set_nbr` actually corresponding to 600 rows, I would like to extract those defined `set_nbr`s family from `data.list`

we use `time` as a `factor` to select `set_nbr`. Here `factor` means as extraction parameter not the real `factor` in R command.

In addition, as you will see four set_nbr exist for each dataset but they are indeed addressing different dataset in the `data.list`

Comment: there's a lot of code that doesn't seem essential to the question. Could you try to formulate a minimal example, isolating the core of your question?

Comment: @baptiste Actually `myfun` is needed because you cannot reach the condition without that function. Besides I put comment for each part what's happening inside of it.

Comment: Then you should narrow down your problem. It seems like you have one big question that is really 3 small questions. "I want to return back to original data.list and select Mx, My, Mz values according those of set_nbr of values." That sounds like Question 1. Maybe make a minimal example of *just that*, then when that part is solved, move on from there.

Comment: @Gregor thanks for advice. I revised my question. please check.

Comment: This is still at least two questions. Graphing the series has nothing to do with extracting the min and max. I will answer the first part. **You should delete the graphing bit from this question and ask it as a separate, new question if you still need help**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big advocate of [using lists of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) when appropriate, but in this case it doesn't look like there's any reason to keep them separated as different list items. Let's combine them into a single data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
dat = bind_rows(data.list)
```

Then getting your summary stats is easy:

```
dat %>% group_by(set_nbr) %>%
    summarize(min_time = min(time),
              max_time = max(time),
              middle_time = median(time))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
#
#   set_nbr min_time max_time middle_time
# 1       1       90    54000       27045
# 2       2       90    54000       27045
# 3       3       90    54000       27045
```

In your sample data, `time` is defined the same way each time, so of course the min, median, and max are all the same.

I'd suggest, in the new question you ask about plotting, starting with the combined data frame `dat`.

As to your second question:

> 2) How to select evaluated set_nbr values inside of data.list?

Selecting a single item from a list, use double brackets

```
data.list[[2]]
```

However, with the combined data, it's just a normal column of a normal data frame so any of these will work:

```
dat[dat$set_nbr == 2, ]
subset(dat, set_nbr == 2)
filter(dat, set_nbr == 2)
```

To your clarification in comments, if you want the Mx and My values for the `time` and `set_nbr` in the `results` object, using my combined `dat` above, simply do a join: `left_join(results, dat)`.

This *should* work, but I'm a little confused because in your simulated data `time` is numeric, but in your new text you say "we use `time` as a `factor`". If you've converted time to a factor object, this will only work if it has the same `levels` in each of the data frames in your data list. If not, I would recommend keeping `time` as `numeric`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I might mixed up some things and not explained the question unique points clearly. You started directly with data.list actually its the main data. We should start with result and select those rows and use them as an extraction parameter from data.list. I revised the question little bit. –

Comment: @aoronbarlow don't change your question once it's been answered. Ask a new question if your question changes.

Comment: Your answer is a bit unsufficient because you are not checking the condition of `result` result and use them in `data.list` to extract the related `set_nbr` datasets.

Comment: @aoronbarlow added a couple paragraphs at the end.

Comment: thanks I checked your comments. On the other hand, I really don`t know even I try to be very clear about my questions why my question still remain hard to catch. Anyway adding `Mx` and `My` columns to the left of `result` is not the thing what I am looking for.

Comment: I am looking for each unique set_nbr from `result` thats understood I believe. Then,  these each `set_nbr` corresponds to 600 column in data.list right? For instance, in the case of `min time` value together with that `Mz`, we have one `set_nbr` lets say 1. I want to extract that `set_nbr` dataset in the data.list with all of `Mx`, `My` and `Mz`.

Comment: I don't understand at all. Can you make your example **minimal**, that is, not 600 rows but maybe 12 rows? And then you can show both your expected input (maybe just `result`?) **and** your expected output? I have no idea what end result you are expecting anymore.

Comment: I am confused because your data.list has three values of `set_nbr`, 1, 2 and 3. Your `result` has the same three values of `set_nbr`. And you say "I want to extract that `set_nbr` dataset with all of Mx, My and Mz". If `set_nbr` is 1, then this is `subset(dat, set_nbr == 1)` or `data.list[[1]]`.

Comment: But let me also say that this question has gone in circles long enough. If you can make a *small, clear, minimal example*, with expected input and output, please ask it as a new question.

Comment: Ok , thanks for advice I`ll make it short and more understandable.